# Remote Desktop solution for Linux machines running Gnome3

Tags: remote-desktop, gnome3, easy-install

I'd like to do Remote Desktoping on a Linux running machine from a Linux machine, both running gnome3.
What are please the easiest to configure, but still secure, solutions?

I'm not sure I'll be able to configure the host router.
So far the only solution coming to mind is NoMachine (as soon as they release NoMachine Network, formerly knows as NoMachine Anywhere), which doesn't require router setup.

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Teamviewer is probably the best option, certainly easiest.

If you're using chrome you could use chrome's remote desktop app

Install guide:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en-GB

Comment: Unfortunately Google is not providing an rpm for the host installation.. but just a deb file :(
I'll try Teamviewer

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Teamviewer?

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

It's free for personal use and can work through firewalls....

After that there are more complex solutions (http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) however they will require either access to the router and port forwarding or ability to configure over SSH which may be a bit tricky if your new to it.

Cheers!

Matt

Comment: even after adding TeamViewer key signature to my system Yumex is not able to install it on my Fedora 23 system.. it gives a dependencies error.